# All active session in mongoDB express-session

Tags: node.js, express-session, connect-mongo

How can i get all active sessions using mongo store with express-session in nodejs. What i have tried is: **`store.all((err,session)=>{ console.log(session); })`**

But its in the same file where i have initialised mongo store, but i'm unable to use this in other files of nodejs. Please help me out of this.